# Code to create spoof animation in iphone

Tags: iphone, animation

I want to make an animation similar to the poof animation(cloud animation: which occurs when an icon  is dragged out of the dock) in macOS. I tried a lot but cannot find any code to do this animation.So please guide me how can i make this animation in iphone. Is there any specific animation for this like shrink, page curl etc or we have to create the animation using png files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such built-in animation, you will have to create it yourself, and, as you suggested, .png files are the recommended format to use in the iPhone, although you are not strictly prevented from using any supported format.

The easiest way might be to use a UIImageView, since it has the capability to animate a series of animations built into it.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use .png files.